# SPOJ Addrev answer not accepted

Tags: c, reverse

I am trying to submit the solution but I am getting wrong answer, but according to me it works fine. There is also the correct code.

My Code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int rev(int num){

 int rev = 0;
 while(num>=10){
    rev = rev + num%10;
    rev=rev*10;
    num = num/10;
 }
   rev = rev + num;
}

int main(){

int T;
int  num1,num2;
scanf("%d",&T);
while(T--){     

    scanf("%d",&num1);
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    printf("%d\n",rev(rev(num1)+rev(num2)));

}

return 0;

}
```

While code that got accepted is

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int rev(int num)
    {
    int temp=0;
    while(num)
    {
        temp=(temp*10)+(num%10);           
        num/=10;
    }
    return temp;
    }
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {   int num1,num2;
        scanf("%d%d",&num1,&num2);
        printf("%d\n",rev(rev(num1)+rev(num2)));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the code was take from http://codegeeksblog.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/spoj-addrev/

I cant find the reason why my code is not accepted! I get wrong answer message from judge.

Comment: The problem is that the `rev(...)` function doesn't actually return anything, ie it has no `return` statements anywhere!  You should be able to compile with warnings on to detect problems like this.

Comment: @msandiford-Thanks for hinting such a common thing,I didn't notice the same! I also edited my answer and mentioned your suggestion...

Comment: sorry, to bother you, i added return statement and it got accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return this num to make the whole function work as hinted by `msandiford`.

Proceed like this in your last step...

```
int rev(int num){

int rev = 0;
while(num>=10){
rev = rev + num%10;
rev=rev*10;
num = num/10;
}
rev = rev + num;  
return rev;         // added a return statement.
}
```